# printing the contents of a Binary Search Tree recursively?

Tags: c++, debugging, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
void MovieTree::printMovieInventory(MovieNode* node)
{
    if(node)
    {
        while(node->rightChild!=NULL or node->leftChild!=NULL)
        {
            std::cout<<"Movie:"<<node->title<<" "<<node->quantity<<std::endl;
            if(node->rightChild)
            {   
                printMovieInventory(node->rightChild);
            }
            if(node->leftChild)
            {
                printMovieInventory(node->leftChild);

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"No movies in list!"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this function is causing my issue or if it's my adding function but I feel as though the logic to this is correct. Am I missing something?

Edit::
My issue is that it's resulting in an infinite loop and it's not properly printing all associated children of the tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of `while` in the function is wrong. It needs to be `if`. Otherwise, the function never breaks out of the `while` loop.

FWIW, that function can be simplified to:

```
void MovieTree::printMovieInventory(MovieNode* node)
{
   if(node)
   {
      std::cout<<"Movie:"<<node->title<<" "<<node->quantity<<std::endl;
      printMovieInventory(node->rightChild);
      printMovieInventory(node->leftChild);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problem with the `while` loop, this can also never print leaf nodes, as you don't print the node itself if it doesn't have either a left or a right child.

```
while(node->rightChild!=NULL or node->leftChild!=NULL)
        {
            std::cout<<"Movie:"<<node->title<<" "<<node->quantity<<std::endl;
```

it should be

```
if(node)
    print node
    if left
       recurse left
    if right
        recurse right
```

Comment: This is a good point. I notice that you're printing in prefix order, whereas the original code was in postfix order. Not sure if that's significant to the task at hand, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @user1118321 original code was postfix?   I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Sorry - not pre/postfix. What I meant was the original code is recursing right first, then left, and yours is left first, then right. Again - not sure it makes any difference, but it could depending on the application.

Comment: @user1118321 While it does not in this context I am curious as to how it would make a difference! Info me please!

Comment: Say you have a parse tree where the nodes can be either operators or operands. If you have a "subtract" operator, then the order of the operands is significant. I have no idea if printing this tree is being used for ordering (such as alphabetical order), but if so, that would also make a difference. (Though in that case you'd have to print the current node between the left and right.)

Comment: @user1118321 ah, I see that now.   left/right is just sort of canonical, so I assumed.   I'll leave it as is since it is generally "how it's done" but neither is right/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Things here.

From the code as i understand, you are trying to print in a pre-order fashion.
the While Loop is unnecessary and that is what is causing the infinite loop
Lets say you have two nodes root and root->left
your function will print root, call the function recursively on root' = root->right (will not print anything this time because root'->left is NULL and root'->right is NULL). Then the function print(root') returns to its caller which is print(root). This time it will not exit out of the while Loop because the while condition is always true, ergo the infinite Loop.

you can simply do this

```
Print(root)
    cout << root;
    if(root->right != NULL)
        Print(root->right);
    if(root->left != NULL)
        Print(root->left);
```

TO display "No Movies" just check if root == NULL before calling this recursive function Print(root);